# Optimizing php sorting function

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, optimization

I got json response (posted below) from server. To compare durations of videos with given time value, currently I'm analyzing every `object->duration` of `results` array with foreach loop. I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any fast way to count objects with duration > 3600 for example (rather than foreach method)?
2. Currently using following `if` (inside foreach loop) to merge items into one array:

   ```
           if ($duration >= $minDuration) {
               $result [] = $tempResult;
   ```

   where (`$tempResult;` is `results`'s current object) Any fast way to pick all items with right durations from array and merge into `$result []` ?

Thx in advance

Here is the JSON:

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'has_next' => boolean true
  public 'next' => string 'http://rutube.ru/api/search/video/?order_by=rank&format=json&no_adult=checked&duration=long&query=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80&page=2' (length=141)
  public 'previous' => null
  public 'page' => int 1
  public 'per_page' => int 10
  public 'results' => 
    array (size=10)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'id' => string '31518e25cde4d110f53d5e9ecde62395' (length=32)
          public 'views' => int 1781
          public 'all_tags' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'author' => 
            object(stdClass)[4]
              ...
          public 'has_high_quality' => boolean false
          public 'duration' => int 1477
          public 'is_adult' => int 0
          public 'thumbnail_url' => string 'http://pic.rutube.ru/video/e1/69/e169d576721998efe85e5a013091792b.jpg' (length=69)
          public 'avatar' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'html' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'title' => string 'АВАТАР' (length=12)
          public 'description' => string 'АВАТАР' (length=12)
          public 'created_ts' => string '2010-08-08T14:50:32' (length=19)
          public 'author_id' => int 0
          public 'track_id' => int 3476481
          public 'aname' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'is_vip' => int 0
          public 'tv_id' => int 0
          public 'tv_title' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'season' => int 0
          public 'episode' => int 0
          public 'category_id' => int 7
          public 'is_licensed' => int 0
          public 'duration_group' => int 5
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[5]
          public 'id' => string 'e5b41d2d7080d5f30fe0e7fca41d5abc' (length=32)
          public 'views' => int 2354
          public 'all_tags' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'author' => 
            object(stdClass)[6]
              ...
          public 'has_high_quality' => boolean false
          public 'duration' => int 1442
          public 'is_adult' => int 0
          public 'thumbnail_url' => string 'http://pic.rutube.ru/video/ac/44/ac44fc73ab015c12fed5f419357c8216.jpg' (length=69)
          public 'avatar' => string 'user/2b/11/2b1160ed4c17b20ab3e9534bb776e212.jpg' (length=47)
          public 'html' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'title' => string 'Аватар' (length=12)
          public 'description' => string 'Аватар' (length=12)
          public 'created_ts' => string '2011-01-15T00:07:50' (length=19)
          public 'author_id' => int 17352
          public 'track_id' => int 3984946
          public 'aname' => string 'Uchiha_Itach1' (length=13)
          public 'is_vip' => int 0
          public 'tv_id' => int 0
          public 'tv_title' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'season' => int 0
          public 'episode' => int 0
          public 'category_id' => int 7
          public 'is_licensed' => int 0
          public 'duration_group' => int 5
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[7]
          public 'id' => string 'f1c72b0afb5e5e9ca867a42af7889b26' (length=32)
          public 'views' => int 336
          public 'all_tags' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'author' => 
            object(stdClass)[8]
              ...
          public 'has_high_quality' => boolean false
          public 'duration' => int 1442
          public 'is_adult' => int 0
          public 'thumbnail_url' => string 'http://pic.rutube.ru/video/0e/6e/0e6ec1dbf789bf296cd4ed24b528545a.jpg' (length=69)
          public 'avatar' => string 'user/2b/11/2b1160ed4c17b20ab3e9534bb776e212.jpg' (length=47)
          public 'html' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'title' => string 'Аватар' (length=12)
          public 'description' => string 'Аватар' (length=12)
          public 'created_ts' => string '2011-01-15T13:01:42' (length=19)
          public 'author_id' => int 17352
          public 'track_id' => int 3986119
          public 'aname' => string 'Uchiha_Itach1' (length=13)
          public 'is_vip' => int 0
          public 'tv_id' => int 0
          public 'tv_title' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'season' => int 0
          public 'episode' => int 0
          public 'category_id' => int 7
          public 'is_licensed' => int 0
          public 'duration_group' => int 5
      3 => 
        object(stdClass)[9]
          public 'id' => string '41c9ac165dde0b35b8604c295772a41e' (length=32)
          public 'views' => int 2684
          public 'all_tags' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'author' => 
            object(stdClass)[10]
              ...
          public 'has_high_quality' => boolean false
          public 'duration' => int 1340
          public 'is_adult' => int 0
          public 'thumbnail_url' => string 'http://tub.rutube.ru/thumbs-wide/a0/e9/a0e92820a935e9ddd6c077532fba3749-1.jpg' (length=77)
          public 'avatar' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'html' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'title' => string 'аватар ' (length=13)
          public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'created_ts' => string '2008-01-02T18:27:32' (length=19)
          public 'author_id' => int 0
          public 'track_id' => int 375879
          public 'aname' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'is_vip' => int 0
          public 'tv_id' => int 0
          public 'tv_title' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'season' => int 0
          public 'episode' => int 0
          public 'category_id' => int 7
          public 'is_licensed' => int 0
          public 'duration_group' => int 5
      4 => 
        object(stdClass)[11]
          public 'id' => string 'ebcd7130e5bcb81be9087495325bcd80' (length=32)
          public 'views' => int 331
          public 'all_tags' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'author' => 
            object(stdClass)[12]
              ...
          public 'has_high_quality' => boolean false
          public 'duration' => int 1442
          public 'is_adult' => int 0
          public 'thumbnail_url' => string 'http://pic.rutube.ru/video/2b/7e/2b7ea182d936de40ea61c2f16cc9a9a6.jpg' (length=69)
          public 'avatar' => string 'user/2b/11/2b1160ed4c17b20ab3e9534bb776e212.jpg' (length=47)
          public 'html' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'title' => string 'Аватар' (length=12)
          public 'description' => string 's2e4-The Swamp.avi' (length=18)
          public 'created_ts' => string '2011-01-16T13:13:46' (length=19)
          public 'author_id' => int 17352
          public 'track_id' => int 3989416
          public 'aname' => string 'Uchiha_Itach1' (length=13)
          public 'is_vip' => int 0
          public 'tv_id' => int 0
          public 'tv_title' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'season' => int 0
          public 'episode' => int 0
          public 'category_id' => int 7
          public 'is_licensed' => int 0
          public 'duration_group' => int 5
      5 => 
        object(stdClass)[13]
          public 'id' => string '21e046d15b879c333677cd224f7f5c22' (length=32)
          public 'views' => int 41019
          public 'all_tags' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'author' => 
            object(stdClass)[15]
              ...
          public 'has_high_quality' => boolean false
          public 'duration' => int 2731
          public 'is_adult' => int 0
          public 'thumbnail_url' => string 'http://pic.rutube.ru/video/8f/94/8f94c671495b2b479dfa57b052dd2efb.jpg' (length=69)
          public 'avatar' => string 'user/33/a1/33a1979db79e1878a9f4b0d1ce860423.jpg' (length=47)
          public 'html' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'title' => string 'Аватар: Легенда о Корре (2 книга) 1-2 серия [озв.Rain.Death]' (length=92)
          public 'description' => string 'Аватар: Легенда о Корре [ТВ-2](2 сезон) 1-2 серия русская озвучка/ Avatar: The Legend of Korra (2 книга) 1-2 серия/ Аватар: Легенда о Корре [ТВ-2](2 сезон) 1-2 серия/ Avatar: The Legend of Korra (2 книга) 1-2 серия' (length=310)
          public 'created_ts' => string '2013-09-14T21:34:27' (length=19)
          public 'author_id' => int 12034
          public 'track_id' => int 6552404
          public 'aname' => string 'D_ENIS' (length=6)
          public 'is_vip' => int 1
          public 'tv_id' => int 0
          public 'tv_title' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'season' => int 0
          public 'episode' => int 0
          public 'category_id' => int 42
          public 'is_licensed' => int 0
          public 'duration_group' => int 5
      6 => 
        object(stdClass)[16]
          public 'id' => string '561d53734809ca73f97b41613cf4a390' (length=32)
          public 'views' => int 25212
          public 'all_tags' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          public 'author' => 
            object(stdClass)[18]
              ...
          public 'has_high_quality' => boolean false
          public 'duration' => int 1423
          public 'is_adult' => int 0
          public 'thumbnail_url' => string 'http://pic.rutube.ru/video/a3/ad/a3ade856840ff611ccdc71fc296c7bf3.jpg' (length=69)
          public 'avatar' => string 'user/33/a1/33a1979db79e1878a9f4b0d1ce860423.jpg' (length=47)
          public 'html' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'title' => string 'Аватар: Легенда о Корре (2 книга) 8 серия [озв.Rain.Death]' (length=90)
          public 'description' => string 'Аватар: Легенда о Корре [ТВ-2](2 сезон) 8 (19) серия русская озвучка/ Avatar: The Legend of Korra (2 книга) 8 серия/ Аватар: Легенда о Корре ' (length=215)
          public 'created_ts' => string '2013-10-19T16:21:11' (length=19)
          public 'author_id' => int 12034
          public 'track_id' => int 6612374
          public 'aname' => string 'D_ENIS' (length=6)
          public 'is_vip' => int 1
          public 'tv_id' => int 0
          public 'tv_title' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'season' => int 0
          public 'episode' => int 0
          public 'category_id' => int 41
          public 'is_licensed' => int 0
          public 'duration_group' => int 5
      7 => 
        object(stdClass)[19]
          public 'id' => string '10d77328a0298537a61a616fba156814' (length=32)
          public 'views' => int 6520
          public 'all_tags' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'author' => 
            object(stdClass)[20]
              ...
          public 'has_high_quality' => boolean false
          public 'duration' => int 1464
          public 'is_adult' => int 0
          public 'thumbnail_url' => string 'http://pic.rutube.ru/video/31/a9/31a97a6067a6f3ac545099d913c26627.jpg' (length=69)
          public 'avatar' => string 'user/33/a1/33a1979db79e1878a9f4b0d1ce860423.jpg' (length=47)
          public 'html' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'title' => string 'Аватар: Легенда о Корре 6 серия[озв.JonEA & Trina D]/ Th...' (length=86)
          public 'description' => string 'Аватар: Легенда о Корре 6 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 6 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 6 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 6 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 6 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 6 серия русская озвучка,The Last Airbender: The Legend of Korra 6 серия,The Last Airbender: The Legend of Korra 6 серия,The Last Airbender: The Legend of Korra '... (length=687)
          public 'created_ts' => string '2012-05-23T13:53:24' (length=19)
          public 'author_id' => int 12034
          public 'track_id' => int 5644436
          public 'aname' => string 'D_ENIS' (length=6)
          public 'is_vip' => int 1
          public 'tv_id' => int 0
          public 'tv_title' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'season' => int 0
          public 'episode' => int 0
          public 'category_id' => int 41
          public 'is_licensed' => int 0
          public 'duration_group' => int 5
      8 => 
        object(stdClass)[21]
          public 'id' => string '7805d6304c142b090bc04c58707a9a01' (length=32)
          public 'views' => int 13909
          public 'all_tags' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'author' => 
            object(stdClass)[22]
              ...
          public 'has_high_quality' => boolean false
          public 'duration' => int 1397
          public 'is_adult' => int 0
          public 'thumbnail_url' => string 'http://pic.rutube.ru/video/6e/8f/6e8f0937d5d36b6e276523a2df8c32a1.jpg' (length=69)
          public 'avatar' => string 'user/33/a1/33a1979db79e1878a9f4b0d1ce860423.jpg' (length=47)
          public 'html' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'title' => string 'Аватар: Легенда о Корре 4 серия[озв.4upik]/ The Last Air...' (length=86)
          public 'description' => string 'Аватар: Легенда о Корре 4 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 4 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 4 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 4 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 4 серия русская озвучка,The Last Airbender: The Legend of Korra 4 серия,The Last Airbender: The Legend of Korra 4 серия,The Last Airbender: The Legend of Korra 4 серия,The Last Airbender: The Legend of Korra 4 �'... (length=710)
          public 'created_ts' => string '2012-04-28T13:17:41' (length=19)
          public 'author_id' => int 12034
          public 'track_id' => int 5574750
          public 'aname' => string 'D_ENIS' (length=6)
          public 'is_vip' => int 1
          public 'tv_id' => int 0
          public 'tv_title' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'season' => int 0
          public 'episode' => int 0
          public 'category_id' => int 41
          public 'is_licensed' => int 0
          public 'duration_group' => int 5
      9 => 
        object(stdClass)[23]
          public 'id' => string '87b6019acda0e9f67091514d27a54eb2' (length=32)
          public 'views' => int 14972
          public 'all_tags' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'author' => 
            object(stdClass)[24]
              ...
          public 'has_high_quality' => boolean false
          public 'duration' => int 1451
          public 'is_adult' => int 0
          public 'thumbnail_url' => string 'http://pic.rutube.ru/video/33/7b/337b3120c6e6a9b43b8f57aefee0016e.jpg' (length=69)
          public 'avatar' => string 'user/33/a1/33a1979db79e1878a9f4b0d1ce860423.jpg' (length=47)
          public 'html' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'title' => string 'Аватар: Легенда о Корре 9 серия[озв.Rain.Deat h]/ The La...' (length=86)
          public 'description' => string 'Аватар: Легенда о Корре 9 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 9 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 9 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 9 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 9 серия,Аватар: Легенда о Корре 9 серия русская озвучка,The Last Airbender: The Legend of Korra 9 серия,The Last Airbender: The Legend of Korra 9 серия,The Last Airbender: The Legend of Korra '... (length=701)
          public 'created_ts' => string '2012-06-10T21:49:28' (length=19)
          public 'author_id' => int 12034
          public 'track_id' => int 5692701
          public 'aname' => string 'D_ENIS' (length=6)
          public 'is_vip' => int 1
          public 'tv_id' => int 0
          public 'tv_title' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'season' => int 0
          public 'episode' => int 0
          public 'category_id' => int 41
          public 'is_licensed' => int 0
          public 'duration_group' => int 5
  public 'count' => int 1000
```

Comment: @ChrisLaplante I var_dumped value from server's json response

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. However, it will be more helpful to post the JSON itself, as opposed to a var_dump of it.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it correctly. While you can use a for loop instead of foreach and gain a few microseconds I would not worry about that. You are obviously downloading a json file so if you're file was so big that 'for' made a difference over 'foreach' you probably would not be downloading it.  The same goes for assigning your result. You are making a copy of each match and adding that to a new array - in a large data situation you might be concerned about memory usage in which case you would use a for loop and keep track of the index of each match in your results array and go from there. But again, if you are dealing with downloading a json file I doubt you are going to experience either of the issues above and I would keep it as is.

Answer (score 0):

for PHP >= 5.3:

```
$results = array_filter($arr, function($var) {
    return $var->duration > 3600;
});

$count = count($results);
```